# What is a dot clock?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: [Running Linux, 5th Edition by Matthias Kalle Dalheimer and Matt Welsh (2006)](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007607.do)

Example:

> Linux started as a real underground movement—guerrilla hacking, if you will—and brings a lot of excitement, discovery, and self-empowerment back into today’s corporate-dominated computing culture. We invite you to dive in, enjoy yourself, and join the throng of people who know what it means to tweak your **dot clocks** and rdev your kernel image.

Literally couldn't find online anything on this. Do any of you happen by any chance to know what exactly those are?

Comment: Sounds like that answer is in the book.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you're not expected to know what "dot clock" and "rdev" mean.  That's what the book presumes to teach you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described by Naba Barkakati in his book *Red Hat Fedora Linux Secrets* <sup>1</sup>
[image: book info - screenshot]
[image: dot clock description - book screenshot]

---

<sup>1</sup> Naba Barkakati, *Red Hat Fedora Linux Secrets* published by [John Wiley & Sons](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/), *http://books.google.com*

Answer (score 1):

**Dot clock** seems to be a reference to video production (so maybe this should be migrated to the video production stack exchange?)

Screens display video (or at least some screens?) by showing rows and rows of dots of color, with only one dot shown at a time. The number of rows determines the video's resolution: 1080p has 1080 rows of dots, 4k has 4000. (EDIT: 4k has ~4000 *columns* of dots)

[See this explanation.](http://video101course.com/300tvcamera110.html)

According to [here](https://pineight.com/mw/index.php?title=Dot_clock_rates) and [here](http://en.tldp.org/HOWTO/XFree86-Video-Timings-HOWTO/basic.html) it seems *dot clock* refers to the speed or frequency at which these dots appear.

Comment: 4K resolution is 3840 x 2160.  And therefore has 2160 “rows”.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's likely to be about video production, though it may be about GPUs and screen output in general.